# Deleting and Finding Elements in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I would just like to know how to fix a minor issue in my code...
The output duplicates the last element in the array when it removes my wanted element. 
Any suggestions?

Here is the code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] List = { 12, 122, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int nrElements =7;
    for (int i = 0; i <= nrElements -1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + List[i] );
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Above is the array");
    Console.WriteLine("What number element do you want to delete?");
    int wanted = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    FindElement(List, nrElements, wanted);
    DeleteElement(List, nrElements, wanted);

    for (int i = 0; i <= nrElements -1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(List[i] +" ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void DeleteElement(int[] list, int nrelement , int wanted)
{
    for (int i = wanted; i <= nrelement - 2; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }
    nrelement--;
}

public static int FindElement(int[] list, int nrElements, int wanted)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= nrElements-1 ; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == wanted)
        { return i; }
        else if (list[i] != wanted)
        { return -1; }               

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: Putting your code in one line, like `{ return i; }` is messy and confusing.  Your app wont be any faster by removing whitespace so do yourself a favor and style your code like the style guide suggests

Comment: `nrelement--` inside method will only affect method's own copy of parameter, but not variable passed as argument to method.

Comment: You can use `list.Length` instead of passing around `nrElements`

Comment: There's dozens of ways of doing this much simpler, SO is not for debugging homework.

Comment: Arrays have a `Length` property. No need to try to track it in another variable. If you use that instead of `nrElements`, it should be ok.'

Comment: Your `FindElement` method returns immediately after examining only the first element (if the first `if` condition is false, then the second one will be true).

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void DeleteElement(int[] list, int nrelement , int wanted)
{
    for (int i = wanted; i <= nrelement - 2; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }
    nrelement--;
}
```

In the above code, `nrelement` is an int, and thus a struct whose value is passed to the method. Changing it's value in the method does not affect anything outside the method.

An immediate solution would be to pass `nrelement` as a `ref` argument, or you could return the value of `nrelement`, and have the caller use that value. However, rethinking the overall design of how you are handling your array (such as using `List<>` instead) might ultimately be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few problems with your code.

First, the `FindElement()` method doesn't quite do what you think it does.

```
public static int FindElement(int[] list, int nrElements, int wanted)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= nrElements - 1; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == wanted)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else if (list[i] != wanted)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you translate the method to English, this is what it does:

- Iterate through the list starting from the beginning.
- See if the first element is what you're looking for.
- If it is, return that index (and exit the method).
- If it is NOT, return -1 and (and exit the method).

So, unless the element you're looking for is in the first index of the list, you won't find it, and will exit the method after one iteration of the loop.

You could fix this with one line of code with LINQ, but I have a feeling that that's not the objective here. I'd do something a little different instead.

- Iterate through the list starting from the beginning.
- See if the first element is what you're looking for.
- If it is, return that index (and exit the method).
- If not, continue the loop to the next iteration and see if the second element is what you're looking for.
- Repeat the above till the end of the list.

So your code should look something like this. And yes, I'd get rid of `nrElements`, you don't need to pass that as a separate parameter. Also, remember to save the result of this method in your `main()` to use in the next method.

```
public static int FindElement(int[] list, int wanted)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        // If item is found in the ith position, retun i;
    }
    // If you reach here, that means the item you're looking for is not in the list. So return -1.
}
```

Next, let's go to your `DeleteElement()` method.

Your use of `nrElement` is incorrect and doesn't make much sense. The fundamental idea of how a `for` loop works is this; start at some initial value, and keep increasing (or decreasing) a counter until a specific condition (value) is met. So what you should normally increase/decrease is the said counter, not the condition it should meet. But at every step you're changing the condition. Which may be justified in rare cases but generally that's now how it's intended to be used.

Next, your way of 'deleting' is problematic as well. What you're really doing is moving elements forward starting at the index of the element you want to delete. So essentially when you're done your last two elements will be the same, your previous last element.

So you'd need to do an `Array.Resize()` after you do the above steps.

```
// Notice the ref.
private static void DeleteElement(ref int[] list, int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < list.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }
    // This step removes the last element from the array.
    Array.Resize(ref list, list.Length - 1);
}
```

Now accordingly you'll need to change your `main()` as well.

- Get rid of the `nrElement`.
- Save the return value of `FindElement()` which is the `index` of the element to delete.
- Use that to see if you found the element to delete.
- If so, pass that to `DeleteElement()`
- Additionally, write a separate method to print a list instead of doing the same thing twice in your `main()`.

---

Above will help you solve the problem using the way you're trying to solve it. But I really do encourage you to completely rethink your approach because there are better ways of doing this.

Few tips:

- Use a C# collection such as a `List<int>` instead of a conventional array.
- You can combine the find and delete methods into one `FindAndDelete()` method.

Hope this helps.